# CakePHP pagination, summary of data retrieved but no data displayed

Tags: php, cakephp

Here is my action

```
    function admin_index()
    {
        $this->paginate = array('limit' => $this->appConfigurations['adminPageLimit'], 'order' => array('price' => 'asc'));
        $this->set('packages', $this->paginate());
    }
```

And my view

```
<?php if($paginator->counter() > 0):?>

<?php echo $this->element('admin/pagination'); ?>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
  <th><?php echo $paginator->sort('name');?></th>
  <th><?php echo $paginator->sort('price');?></th>
  <th class="actions"><?php __('Options');?></th>
</tr>
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach ($packages as $package):
  $class = null;
  if ($i++ % 2 == 0) {
    $class = ' class="altrow"';
  }
?>
<tr<?php echo $class;?>>
    <td>
        <?php echo $package['BuyItPackage']['name']; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $number->currency($package['BuyItPackage']['price'], $appConfigurations['currency']); ?>
    </td>
    <td class="actions">
        <?php if($this->requestAction('/settings/enabled/multi_languages'))     : ?>
            <?php echo $html->link(__('Edit', true), array('action'=>'translations', $package['BuyItPackage']['id'])); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

The pagination part displays
    Showing 1 - 5 (5)

And the table headers displayed but no data is displayed, it seems like the foreach code is not entered.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to remove  first if  in view and check

Comment: Actually if I click one of the table headers to sort the data then the rows are displayed, so how do I set the sort so they are displayed straight off the bat?

Comment: May be. i am not sure. do it and check

Comment: How do I do that, was my question

Comment: First try to check $packages have any value or not?

Comment: It does, var_dump($packages); has the data but only when a sort table header is clicked

Comment: try to put your code on fiddle then only problem is resolved